# Spring boot gradle bootRun is very slow

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

It takes around 10 mins to run on my machine. I tried to run in debug mode. These logs keeps repeating in that time

```
14:42:42.517 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
14:42:42.517 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
14:42:42.520 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
14:42:42.523 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
14:42:42.523 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
14:42:42.525 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
14:42:46.173 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 17179869184, Free: 7042408448}
14:42:46.173 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 17179869184, Free: 7042408448}
14:42:46.173 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 954728448, Committed: 760741888}
```

Is it supposed to happen like this? Or I can improve something.